# WCF Dependency injection and abstract factory

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I have this wcf method

```
Profile GetProfileInfo(string profileType, string profileName)
```

and a business rule:

if profileType is "A" read from database.

if profileType is "B" read from xml file.

The question is: how to implement it using a dependency injection container?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Let's first assume that you have an IProfileRepository something like this:

```
public interface IProfileRepository
{
     Profile GetProfile(string profileName);
}
```

as well as two implementations: `DatabaseProfileRepository` and `XmlProfileRepository`. The issue is that you would like to pick the correct one based on the value of profileType.

You can do this by introducing this **Abstract Factory**:

```
public interface IProfileRepositoryFactory
{
    IProfileRepository Create(string profileType);
}
```

Assuming that the IProfileRepositoryFactory has been injected into the service implementation, you can now implement the GetProfileInfo method like this:

```
public Profile GetProfileInfo(string profileType, string profileName)
{
    return this.factory.Create(profileType).GetProfile(profileName);
}
```

A concrete implementation of IProfileRepositoryFactory might look like this:

```
public class ProfileRepositoryFactory : IProfileRepositoryFactory
{
    private readonly IProfileRepository aRepository;
    private readonly IProfileRepository bRepository;

    public ProfileRepositoryFactory(IProfileRepository aRepository,
        IProfileRepository bRepository)
    {
        if(aRepository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aRepository");
        }
        if(bRepository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bRepository");
        }

        this.aRepository = aRepository;
        this.bRepository = bRepository;
    }

    public IProfileRepository Create(string profileType)
    {
        if(profileType == "A")
        {
            return this.aRepository;
        }
        if(profileType == "B")
        {
            return this.bRepository;
        }

        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Now you just need to get your DI Container of choice to wire it all up for you...

Comment: Those sequential `ifs` could be replaced be a faster/more legible `switch/case`.  And `profileType` really should be an enumeration, not an arbitrary string.  Other than that it's a great answer. :)

Comment: Yes, no disagreement there, but I just went with the API given by the OP :)

Comment: In which way it can change if i don't know at compile time the number of repositories?
And if my wcf have only dependencies with log library and these repositories, where is the best DI Container choice?

is MEF a good choiche in this scenario?

Comment: just a little clarification:i'll use the lo library for logging custom message in method and not for tracing

Comment: You can configure most DI Containers using XML configuration, which is a good option when you don't know all the repositories at compile time, but MEF might also be a good option in this case.

Comment: In what package would you suggest placing the `ProfileRepositoryFactory` class? In the composition root (it concerns object creation), in the service layer (this is a business rule) or alongside the actual repository implementations?

Comment: @MEMark That depends :) If it contains significant business logic, it should go in the Domain Model so that it can be properly tested, but that also means that it would have to be a [Manually Coded Factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory); otherwise, you can put it in the Composition Root, in which case you have fewer implementation constraints.

Comment: Why don't you just add a profileType parameter to GetProfile ?

Answer (score 6):

Great answer by Mark, However the solution given is not **Abstract factory** but the implementation of Standard **Factory** pattern. Please check how Marks classes fit in the Standard Factory Pattern UML diagram. [Click here to see above classes applied to Factory pattern UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaK66.png)

Since in Factory pattern, the factory is aware of the concrete classes, we can make the code of the `ProfileRepositoryFactory` much simpler like below. The problem with injecting the different repositories to factory is that you have more code changes every time you add a new concrete type. With below code you only have to update the switch to include new concrete class

```
    public class ProfileRepositoryFactory : IProfileRepositoryFactory
    {
        public IProfileRepository Create(string profileType)
        {
            switch(profileType)
            {
                case "A":
                    return new DatabaseProfileRepository(); 

                case  "B":
                    return new XmlProfileRepository();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Abstract Factory** is more advanced pattern used for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes. The UML class diagram available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) explains it well.